# question about ros2 bag play

Tags: ros2, rosbag

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am tried to use **ros2 bag record** to save the information of camera topic, but how to use **ros2 bag play** to loop play the package.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/328687/question-about-ros2-bag-play/) by [RachelRen](https://answers.ros.org/users/35425/rachelren/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-16

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In ROS1 you could loop play using the `-l` command.

However, it appears that this has not been implemented yet in ROS2.

You can follow the development of rosbag for ROS2 here
https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2

---

Originally posted by [alsora](https://answers.ros.org/users/30341/alsora/) with karma: 1322 on 2019-07-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Karsten](https://answers.ros.org/users/8211/karsten/) on 2019-07-17**:
I can't mark your answer as correct even though it is :) rosbag2 doesn't have capabilities yet to play the data in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The option has been implemented in April 2020 (https://github.com/ros2/rosbag2/commit/12c0cc6d783970d2e7570cc5d25d2b49695d411c)

Use the -l (or --loop) option:

```
ros2 bag play <bagfile.db3> --loop
```

---

Originally posted by [Ruthven](https://answers.ros.org/users/9811/ruthven/) with karma: 26 on 2020-11-19

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [leochien](https://answers.ros.org/users/149826/leochien/) on 2023-05-19**:
This one works, thanks!